# Does <jsp:forward> or RequestDispatcher.forward use GET or POST?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, forwarding

The question is in the title: Does `<jsp:forward>` or `RequestDispatcher.forward` use GET or POST to do its thing?

If it uses one, can I always count it will be that one or can this vary from server to server?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither; it directly looks up the servlet class in your container and then calls the dispatcher.

The dispatcher will examine the type of the request and call the appropriate method. So if the original request was `POST`, `doPost()` will be called.

Comment: Is a servlet container obliged to to that? I mean, if a request arrives on GET is it possible that the server will call doPost() on the target?

Comment: you can always direct both doGet and doPost to doStuff()

Comment: @Bozho: Not when your target is a Spring controller who distinguishes between GET and POST (e.g. formBackingObject on GET, onSubmit on POST)

Comment: @user1010: Which method is called depends solely on the request type that is stored in the HttpRequest instance. It works the same for all containers. Unless you specifically modify the request instances, all subsequent servlets will be called with the same method. So `GET` requests will **never** invoke `doPost()` unless you tamper with the request type.