# servlet calling and getting result from another servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to get the result from servlet (B) within servlet (A) and react to the result.

e.g.

in servlet B

```
response.getWriter().print("HELLO");
```

in servlet A

```
ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/B");
dispatcher.include(request, response);

// if the response from B is "HELLO", then do something
```

What would be the best practice for the solution? or should the way it response in servlet B would be changed to other method?

Comment: Can't you simply move the generation of "HELLO" to common component both servlets would use?

Comment: You are most likely missusing the concept of servlets. If you explain what is the broader context we might suggest better solution.

Comment: as I said, I just want to fetch some result from another sevlet and react to it

Answer (score 0):

***you should use this method:***

1. use a `RequestDispatcher`
2. use a `URLConnection` or `HTTPClient`
3. send a `redirect`
4. call `getServletContext().getServlet(name)`

***[Calling Servlet Post from another Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780103/calling-servlet-post-from-another-servlet)***