# Spring-MVC 3.1: Forwarding A Request From One Controller Function To Another

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using  Spring 3.1.   I have a controller function that takes in a command object ( a data holder ) submitted via a FORM and does some processing :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String toResultsScreen(@ModelAttribute("ssdh") SearchScreenDataHolder ssdh,
                                  BindingResult bindingResult,    
                                  ModelMap model,                
                                  HttpSession session) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        logger.debug("Error returning to /search screen");
        return "search";
    }

    netView = "results";

    // do stuff

    return nextView;         

} // end function
```

Some user would like to programmatically make GET links to obtain information from our site and I would like to set up another handler that would handle that request.   It would create a new installation of that the command object ( ssdh ) and populate it with the parameters sent via the GET request.   Then it would pass it on to the handler above.   Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pubresult")
public String toPublicResultsScreen(ModelMap model,    
                                   HttpSession session,             
                                   @RequestParam (required=true) String LNAME,   
                                   @RequestParam (required=false)String FNAME){

    Search search = new Search(usertype);

    // Capture the search parameters sent by HTTP
    ssdh.setLast_name(LNAME);
    ssdh.setFirst_name(FNAME);

    // To Do:  "forward this data holder, ssdh to the controller function quoted first

    return nextView;         

} // end function
```

My question is how can I forward my command/data holder object to the first controller function such that I don't have to alter the code to the first controller function in any way?

Answer (score 18):

You can use `RedirectAttributes` object which was introduced in Spring MVC 3.1 and populate it with data you want to keep for redirection. It called PRG (POST/Redirect/GET) pattern.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveUserDetails.action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String greetingsAction(@Validated User user,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    //setting attributes 
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("firstName", user.getFirstName());
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("lastName", user.getLastName())
    return "redirect:success.html";
}
```

I wrote some technical article regarding how to use it. I believe it will give you more details:

http://www.tikalk.com/java/redirectattributes-new-feature-spring-mvc-31

Comment: @danny.lesnik The link http://www.tikalk.com/java/redirectattributes-new-feature-spring-mvc-31 you have provided is broken. Will u update this with working link ?

Comment: Why do I need to do this event with a forward?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to set the ssdh in a ModelAttribute and simply forward it back, this way, the RequestDispatcher should be able to map it back to the `/results` handler:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pubresult")
public String toPublicResultsScreen(ModelMap model,    
                                   HttpSession session,             
                                   @RequestParam (required=true) String LNAME,   
                                   @RequestParam (required=false)String FNAME, Model model){

  Search search = new Search(usertype);
  // Capture the search parameters sent by HTTP
  ssdh.setLast_name(LNAME);
  ssdh.setFirst_name(FNAME);
  model.addAttribute("ssdh", ssdh);

  return "forward:/results";         

}
```

Comment: I tried this out.  The controller function I want to forward to handles POST requests.  When I try to forward from the the function in the example above, which does GET requests. I get an error message saying that GET requests are not support.  I'm guessing I can't forward a GET request to a POST function.  Is there a way for me to change the request type before forwarding to get it to end up at the same URL?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I read up a little on the request method at the point of forward - it will continue to be the same request method as the original request, so in this case, since you are calling /pubresult over HTTP GET, this will be maintained in the forwarded request also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374548/does-jspforward-or-requestdispatcher-forward-use-get-or-post. Not sure if there is a workaround, if feasible have the same RequestMethod for both

Answer (score 0):

Use

> org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView

class from spring package to redirect to different page in spring MVC controller. [The Baeldung blog page has more details](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward)

Sample code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView mainMethod() {
    return new RedirectView("/login");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView mainLogin() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
    return model;
}
```