# Inconsistent error: Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Using Spring REST API [Spring MVC]

**Scenario:**

when request comes to the `EmployeeController` , it is forced to forward the request/response to another URI,if it falls under a specific logic.
The controller method has `RequestMapping` set with '`RequestMethod.POST`' and the destination controller- `SpecialController` has the  `method` named `invalidRequest()` that has `RequestMapping` set with '`RequestMethod.GET`'

**EmployeeController:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    String res = null;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateEmployeeDetails(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
            @Valid @RequestBody Employee emp) throws ServletException, IOException {
         // based on logic, forward the request to a different controller that handles invalid request

    if( ...) { // condition checking
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = httpRequest.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/invalidRequest");
        requestDispatcher.forward(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    
    }

   if(..someother condition..) {
        String res = "something";
   }
return res;
```

**Destination Controller:**

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/invalidRequest")
    public class SpecialController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String invalidRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
            httpResponse.setStatus(401);
            return "invalidRequest";
        }

    }
```

**Question:** **Inconsistency Problem [Actual Problem]:**

In 90% of the times, this is working, but a few times very rarely, I get the below error.
If I am getting this error always, then it would have made some meaning and I would have the below mentioned '*possible fix*'
But since it is working most of the times, and not working only sometimes, I need your help in finding out why?

```
> org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
> Request method 'POST' not supported
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:198)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:286)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:233)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:56)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:300)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1101)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:916)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
```

**possible fix if the error was consistent:**

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/invalidRequest")
    public class SpecialController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String invalidRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
            httpResponse.setStatus(401);
            return "invalidRequest";
        }
        
        @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String invalidRequest2(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
            return invalidRequest(httpRequest, httpResponse);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you enable DEBUG logging and check to which URL the requests are going?

Comment: Why not to use the same method for the controller?

Comment: the request is going to `/invalidRequest`

Comment: you are forwarding POST to GET???? you should use something like redirect [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11960845/1996296)

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to populate any data. The link inside that answer is a broken link. How do I say redirect to this request "/invalidRequest" ? and Why is this inconsistent? Most of the times my code is working

Comment: Who's calling it? A human or a robot? Just check access logs.

Comment: something like that `return "redirect:success.html";` you can look at the link I put in the comment

Comment: use `@Modelattribute` in `@Valid @RequestBody Employee emp`. You should do something like `@Valid @RequestBody @ModelAttribute("emp") Employee emp`

Comment: Sometimes means session is ended? are you using csrf tokens? If yes, try refereshing page before submission.