# Consuming custom error response from Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, error-handling

I want to implement custom error pages for error codes with messages.
Following baeldung guide so far i got this on the backend;

Custom Exception:

```
 public class TicketNotFoundException extends RuntimeException
{
    public TicketNotFoundException(Long id)
    {
        super("Ticket not found with id: "+id);
    }
}
```

Custom Response:

```
public class CustomErrorResponse
{
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private int status;
    private String error;
//getters setters
 }
```

Custom Exception Handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{

    @ExceptionHandler(value = TicketNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomErrorResponse> customHandleNotFound(Exception ex)
    {
        CustomErrorResponse errors = new CustomErrorResponse();
        errors.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        errors.setError(ex.getMessage());
        errors.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

And Response itself works:

> { timestamp: "2020-04-13 09:33:52", status: 404, error: "Ticket not
>   found with id: 1" }

Backend terminal:

```
 Resolved [com.eggorko.ebt.ticket.TicketNotFoundException: Ticket not found with id: 1]
```

So my question is what should I do on the client side?

Client controller looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String ticket(@PathVariable Long id, Model model)
    {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/ticket/";
        ResponseEntity<Ticket> ticket = restTemplate.getForEntity( url+ id, Ticket.class);

        model.addAttribute("ticket",ticket.getBody());
        model.addAttribute("title","Tickets");
        return "ticket";
    }
```

I did this bit client side, but it doesn't work:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController
{
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest  request)
    {
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

        if (status != null) {
            Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

            if(statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "error-404";
            }
            else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "error-500";
            }
        }
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath()
    {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

This is what i got in terminal on client:

```
2020-04-13 10:34:40.559 ERROR 12868 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 : [{"timestamp":"2020-04-13 10:34:40","status":404,"error":"Ticket not found with id: 1"}]] with root cause
```

And it's goes to 500 error page, instead of 404.

I sort of understand why it doesn't work. I don’t have anything handling error on the client side and it goes to error 500. But i don’t know what to do with it.

UPDATE
So i did this:

```
 String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/ticket/";
            try {
                ResponseEntity<Ticket> ticket = restTemplate.getForEntity(url + id, Ticket.class);
                model.addAttribute("ticket",ticket.getBody());
                model.addAttribute("title","Tickets");
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                String msg = e.getMessage();
                model.addAttribute("message",msg);
                return "/error";
            }
   return "ticket";
```

And now at least i'm getting a error page with the actual message from backend. But this solution is working around MyErrorController. MyErrorController dosen't fire and basicly obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning view name from your MyErrorController, do you have a error page errro.html or error.jsp (whatever suffix you are using for your view resolver) at the location you specified in view resolver? Morever you are using same error page for all error code you can create multiple error pages for different error codes say error-404.jsp and error-500.jsp. Another approach is to return the ModelAndView instead of view name, you can refer to [link](https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exception-handling-example/).

**UPDATE**

Ok now i get what are you trying to achieve, It is giving 500 because you are not handling exception in your client controller, when you are making rest template call you are saying i want a response of Ticket type but you are getting response of CustomErrorResponse, determine which exception it is throwing either by console log or catching the exception and then handle it and do your processing.

```java
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String ticket(@PathVariable Long id, Model model)
    {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/ticket/";
        try
        {
        ResponseEntity<Ticket> ticket = restTemplate.getForEntity( url+ id, 
        Ticket.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         // handel exception
        }

        model.addAttribute("ticket",ticket.getBody());
        model.addAttribute("title","Tickets");
        return "ticket";
    }
```

OR

You can wrap your Ticket and CustomErrorResponse is a parent class and then can use instance of to determine which response you received

```java
ResponseEntity<Parent> parent= restTemplate.getForEntity( url+ id, 
        Parent.class);
if(parent.getBody() instanceof Ticket)
{
//normal flow
}
else
{
//error
}
```

**UPDATE2**

ErrorController is obsolete because

```java
String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/ticket/";
            try {
                ResponseEntity<Ticket> ticket = restTemplate.getForEntity(url + id, Ticket.class);
                model.addAttribute("ticket",ticket.getBody());
                model.addAttribute("title","Tickets");
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                String msg = e.getMessage();
                model.addAttribute("message",msg);
                return "/error";
            }
   return "ticket";
```

is returning a view error.jsp(or .html) with model, it is not redirecting to URL /error, you can do that by using redirect [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960719/spring-mvc-3-1-forwarding-a-request-from-one-controller-function-to-another?answertab=votes#tab-top), but I suggest not to, your ErrorController is mean to deal error occurred in your application not in some application your application in calling to, implement a proper response page for such condition.

Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah, all the views are there. Same “error” thing it's just a thing i tried to do, i changed it back how it's supposed to be. I wasn't clear enough what the probmlem was, I will edit the post.

Comment: I'm getting there. Thank you for your help. I will update what i did.